# how to make Azure Function using Blob Trigger await until the all files is loaded completely to the container in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, containers, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure function application and I'm using 5 or 6 blob trigger function in my project, I publish my project to azure and I need the function app to be executed after all the files is loaded completely to the container because some files in the input need to be executed before other files ! any idea ?

Comment: I'm on a consumption app, yeah exactly I want perform  all of the business logic after 15 minutes, not when the files is uploaded to the container in Azure.

Comment: I'm on a consumption app, yeah exactly I want perform  all of the business logic after 15 minutes, not when the files is uploaded to the container in Azure.

Comment: And what is the difference between premium and consumption and how will it help me in my case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I Edit my response, I think it's more clear now !
if any thing is not clear please tell me !

Comment: You’ll just need to orchestrate it given the services available. You don’t have an issue as such, you want help to architect the solution, that’s not really what SO is here for you. Make an attempt and then come back with a specific issue, sorry but that’s my advice.

Comment: Do you think this is my problem  : " Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting. " ?

Comment: No that is not your problem, that just means you are running from a ZIP file is one way of running functions and some instances the preferred way

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an architecture question than a code question but one way to solve this is to have one function that checks for all the files as they trigger and once it is happy that all files is there places a message to a event HUB that a receiver picks up and then processes the files or you can do it all in one function just have to have it check for all the files it eneds before trying to use them, or you can use a wide variety of other services in azure to achieve the same thing, but without showing us what you have tried and any specific error messages it is hard to give detailed advice